# Cypress - Debugging after:run error thrown in plugin files wile executing

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have a cypress with cucumber preprocessor use. Works fine in "open" (Manually close the session) but when running execution I get:

An error was thrown in your plugins file while executing the handler for the after:run event.

```
  An error was thrown in your plugins file while executing the handler for the after:run event.

The error we received was:

Error: spawn cucumber-json-formatter.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
```

Any simple fixes suggested or how should I start with debugging this?

The thrown error prevents the --reporter from running

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What does your cypress.config look like? I had this same error and it went away when I added:

```
on('before:run', async (details) => {
  console.log('override before:run');
  await beforeRunHook(details);
}),
on('after:run', async () => {
  console.log('override after:run');
  await afterRunHook();
})
```

to setupNodeEvents